# why doesn't binarySearch method return the correct result?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

Recently I am working on arrays in Java and I needed to use the method `binarySearch(arr, v)` in Arrays class to search the index of value `v` in the array `arr` if found.

Then I do some tests with some different arrays. When I try to search value `4` in the array `{4, 3, 2, 1}` I found `-5`.

Would someone can explain that please ?

You can check here http://tpcg.io/kibBmw

The code is below:

```
int[] arr   = {4, 3, 2, 1};
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 4));
```

> -5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `Arrays.sort(arr);` before the binary search. From the documentation for [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-):

> Searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the binary search algorithm. The array **must be sorted** (as by the sort(int[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Comment: Ahhh Okay ! Thank you very much. I remember then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). You need to have a sorted array to use this method. You can do the following:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 4)
```

Comment: Cool ! I just forgot it. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

For using standard binary search algorithm your input array must be in increasing value order otherwise you will get unexpected results.